# How to simplify the code with two overloads of the function that get Func and Action as a parameter?

Tags: c#, generics, action, functor, func

1. Is it a way to make such code simpler? Yes, I know that the code in the comment can be extracted as a method, but it is a bit confusing to write such two overloads every time. Note that there can be other parameters than `functor` in a function like `DoSomething`.

   ```
   Result DoSomething<Result>(Func<Parameter, Result> functor)
   {
       // do something to construct argument
       return functor(argument);
   }

   void DoSomething(Action<Parameter> functor)
   {
       // do something to construct argument
       functor(argument);
   }
   ```
2. More complex variant. How to achieve the same result without code duplication if a `functor` call is inside a `using` block?

In fact I want to find a C# alternative to the C++14 code like

```
template <class Functor>
auto DoSomething(Functor functor)
{
    // do something...
    return functor(argument);
}
```

Comment: it appears that `argument` is undeclared.

Comment: @abelenky Assume it is declared inside the `// do something...` block of the code.

Comment: Well you could call `DoSomething<int>(p => {action(p); return 1;});` and ignore the returned value to get the `Action` to work in the `Func` overload.

Comment: @juharr Good, thank you. But such solution is a bit dirty trick, isn't it? It's like a hack.

Comment: @Constructor Yeah, which is why I didn't make in an answer.  Personally I usually do both overloads in cases where I think they are both needed.  In fact my specific case was to simplify the use of a `using(var con = new SqlConnection(...))` to wrap around the "functor".

Comment: @juharr The code in `// do something` block may be long enough to copy-paste it.

And what about automatization of the process of writing such two overloads?

Comment: @Constructor Are you forced to implement these via interface?

Comment: @ebeeb No, do you have other suggestions?

Comment: @Constructor Well if the `// do something` is long you should put it into a separate method as you mentioned rather than copy and paste.  As for automation, I'm not sure exactly what you mean.  Are you using a code generator tool or writing your own?

Comment: @juharr 1) I mean the second (more complex) part of the question. In a simple case I can extract new method, of course. 2) I want to automate this process at a language level without use of code generators.

Comment: @Constructor could you elaborate your problem with more code or insight? As it seems so far you cut the implementations down to one line each. And these implementations are substantially different from each other. One returns a value and the other doesn't. I think without more insight you cannot really simplify your code.

Comment: @ebeeb In C++ one can simply write `template <class Functor> auto DoSomething(Functor functor){ /* do something...*/ return functor(argument); }` and `DoSomething` function can get both `functor`s that return `void` and non`void` values. I want to achive the same functionality in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could create a `FuncWrapper<Parameter, Result>` generic class with implicit conversions from `Func<Parameter, Result>` and `Action<Parameter>` and a `Call(Parameter)` function that performs the actual call.

The FuncWrapper can have two members (a Func<...> and Action<...>) and call through the one that isn't null, or you can wrap the Action<...> with a lambda expression that essentially turns it into a Func<...> (call the action, return default(Result))

Then you define just one function in your class:

```
Result DoSomething(FuncWrapper<Parameter, Result> wrapper)
{
    // Find argument
    return wrapper.Call(argument);
}
```

Your `FuncWrapper` class should return `default(Result)` value in case the `Action<Parameter>`.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you. Why is *.NET* lack of such `FuncWrapper` class?

Comment: Could you explain how to store information about `FuncWrapper` real type between its construction and calling of the `Call` method?

Comment: Probably because it's rather confusing, this kind of implicit conversions hides what's really going on.